# Remove SQL Dependencies from SharePoint Standalone Cloned VM

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, environment

I have made a copy of a standalone SP 2010 VM -> VM_2. I've renamed it, defined another IP. Now VM_1 and VM_2 run simultaneously. I've added following line to hosts file:

```
MY_NEW_IP VM_1 VM_2
```

to redirect the request to itself.

**Problem:** There're still references from VM_2 to SQL Server on VM_1 according to `netstat -a -o`

**Question:** Is there a solution to completely remove these dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct sequence of steps:

> Rename computer => Reboot computer =>
>   stsadm -o renameserver => iisreset =>
>   fix alternate mappings => Reboot
>   computer => Restart All SharePoint
>   Services